# Spring boot application need to connect weblogic oracle datasource

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The spring boot application by default is connecting to derby embedded database as shown in the below statement.

Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:derby:memory:testdb;create=true', username='sa'

I don't know where it is picking the above url from

I need to connect weblogic oracle datasource I gave the following properties in the application.properties of the application but its not picking the below properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=vasu
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
```

Added the following entry in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.noraui</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am co-creator of com.github.noraui, this jar file is deprecated, please use this sample: github.com/sgrillon14/MavenSampleOracleJdbc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you already have your oracle datasource defined in the weblogic, so you don't need neither oracle driver in your application classpath nor `spring.datasource.{url,username,password,driver-class-name}` properties defined.

What you need instead is `spring.datasource.jndi-name` property. Just set it to jndi name of your datasource from weblogic and spring will pickup it just like that.

Of course you have to have an oracle driver in weblogic classpath (lib directory or something like that).

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jdbc/OracleDS
```

[Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-a-jndi-datasource).

Comment: Hi. Do you know how can I do if the webapp is not in the localhost?. Something like this: "spring.datasource.jndi-name: t3//192.151.110.180:7001/jdbc/conEsos"

Comment: @J.Abel did you able to find answer to your question?

Comment: Yes I can get it, however I can not do it from the application.config file. I did it from a @Configuration class.

Comment: @J.Abel I am trying to figureout that one as well but couldn't find the solution yet. Can you give me some hint?